# Makara gem and jquery-ui issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to add makara (https://github.com/taskrabbit/makara) to an RoR project. My app works fine, but as soon as I bundle install makara I can't access any jquery.ui files. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Part of gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~>3.2.17'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
...
...
gem 'makara', github: 'taskrabbit/makara', tag: 'v0.2.2'
...
```

Error:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
```

Edit:
Also, the error still gets thrown if I remove the gem and bundle install/update, even though the app worked perfectly fine before makara was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, was a syntax issue on my part. My guess is jquery.ui.--- was deprecated, so when I hit bundle install my code broke.

'jquery.ui.datepicker' should be 'jquery-ui/datepicker'.